# How do I create a dynamic html table showing mysql query results using ejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

New to coding, so I apologize for any rookie mistakes.

I am attempting to query a MySQL database and return the results to a table.  I will be submitting the SQL query via a form on the site, so the number and names of the columns will be dynamic.  I have seen how this is done in PHP but I would like to do this via node.js and ejs.  I have been able to figure out how to have all the rows of the query results show in a table.  Here are examples of the code.
query.ejs

```
<table id="table" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <% print.forEach(function (RowDataPacket) { %>
      <tr>
         <td><%= RowDataPacket.id %></td>
         <td><%= RowDataPacket.name %></td>
      </tr>
      <% }) %>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js

```
app.post("/query", function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body.sql);
var sqlStatement = req.body.sql;
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
if (err) {
    throw err;
} else {
    obj = {
        print: result
    };
    res.render('query', obj);
}
});
```